# TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a hangman game in python. I have the words which I will be using for the game in a txt file and I wish to read this file line by line and append the contents to a list for use; however I am encountering this TypeError. (object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len())

```
try:
    f = open(input("Enter a filename: "))
except:
    print("Cannot open file")
    quit()

myList = []
myLine = f.readline()
print(myLine)
print(len(myLine))

while len(myLine) >0 :
    myList.append(myLine)
    myLine = f.readline
```

The error is regarding

```
while len(myLine) >0 :
```

This is confusing me a lot as the calls to print(myLine) and print(len(myLine)) immediately above are working correctly, outputting the contents of the line and its length; it is only when I enter the while loop that I am getting this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your while loop, you probably meant:

```
myLine = f.readline()
```

If you don't call the method (e.g. have the parenthesis on there), then you're assigning a method to `myLine` (instead of the method's *result*) and methods have no defined length.

For what it's worth though, there's an easier way to get the list of lines in the file:

```
myList = list(f)
```

should do the job nicely.

Comment: Wow that was it, thank you so much. I knew it would be something silly like that; but an hour of searching and I still couldn't see it.
Thanks again.

Comment: @user3081556 -- No problem.  Happy to lend a hand.